# Application runs faster in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I have a runnable java SE application in eclipse. I bootstrap JPA to work in a normal java 6 SE environment. Each request to the different tables in the database doesn't take more than 100ms.

The problem is that when I export the runnable jar and I say java -jar myapp.jar, each of the request to the database take around 9 seconds.

I don't Understand why the application is faster when I run it from eclipse

Comment: How did you measure it? which vm args did you use to run the process?

Comment: I measure it by logging the calculated time in miliseconds. I use Log4j and the logging level is the same = "DEBUG"

Comment: Yes but the question is "Is it using the same DB"? If it is a different schema with tables full of records and the one used by eclipse has only few records, you may need to tune up your DB by adding proper indexes

Comment: Are you sure that eclipse is using the same jvm that when you launch the app?

Comment: no, they are accessing the same ip, the same port, the same schema.

Comment: eclipse and java -version show me this JRE: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, each time I was doing a request to the database, I was creating an entity manager:

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "mysqldb" );
```

In order to optimize the creation of the entity manager I use a singleton entity factory like that:

```
private static EntityManagerFactory em = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory( "mysqldb" );

public static EntityManagerFactory getEmf()
{
    return em;
}
```

this worked to improve the performance of the application outside eclipse, but there is no change in the performance when i run it inside eclipse.

I am not really sure of what is the reason it worked better when the application was launched from eclipse, but this solution solved my problem for the moment.

Comment: +1 for sorting your own issue out and following up on here - good to hear you got somewhere with it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of how to use eclipse compiler. The ant script used by eclipse is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project Server">
<!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard-->
<!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->
<target name="create_run_jar">
    <jar destfile="myapp.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="myapp.main.Main"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
        </manifest>
        <fileset dir="dir.../Myapp/build/classes"/>
        <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src=
            ..exclude all libraries
    </jar>
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use -verbose:class on both versions to see if it's loading different versions of the classes which are causing the slowdown

Comment: when I add -verbose:class in the configuration of eclipse I get the list of classes. When I export the jar or when I run java -jar myapp.jar -verbose:class nothing is shown.

Comment: Put the -verbose:class before the -jar

Comment: sorry. I generated a file with the console output of the class loading and I used diff in the console to compare the files. The big difference is that the libraries in case of eclipse are loaded from the user libraries I created, while in the other case the classes are loaded from the libraries contained in the jar. I really don't think this can be the problem

Comment: No that sounds absolutely fine. Have to think of something else.

Comment: I just post a possible answer