# Eclipse program runs faster than after it is exported

Tags: java, eclipse, game-engine, delta

Problem: I have a program that involves moving a bar (like in brick break) from side to side. The issue is that it moves at a different speed when running inside Eclipse than it does exported to the desktop.

Research:

When reading this it makes me think that I **might not be creating my delta value correctly** which could explain why it runs at different speeds.
[my computer is carrying out java programs which i have created to fast [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419527/my-computer-is-carrying-out-java-programs-which-i-have-created-to-fast)

After reading this post I found that maybe the **Eclipse compiler is just faster** which can cause the difference in speeds.
[Application runs faster in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903250/application-runs-faster-in-eclipse)

```
    // run() is being ran with a while(true) game loop
    public void run(Input input)
    {
         init();
         // Ran at 60 FPS
         if(fps.tick())
              render();
         // Ran as fast as possible
         update(input);
    }

    private void render()
    {
         start = System.nanoTime();     

         if(render.getGraphics() != null)
         {
             Graphics g = render.getBS().getDrawGraphics();
             g.drawImage(new BufferedImage(Reference.WIDTH*Reference.SCALE, Reference.HEIGHT*Reference.SCALE, 
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB), 0,0, AppGameContainer.canvas);
             activeState.render(render.getGraphics(), AppGameContainer.canvas);
             render.getGraphics().dispose();
             render.getBS().show();
         }
         end = System.nanoTime();

         // Time in ms
         delta =  (end-start)/1000000.0;
    }
```

I have a video **if interested** for a visual representation of the problem: [Video of issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htzmT6CJb0c&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Disable any throttling (fps.tick()) and see if it's still slower. If it isn't, your code is the problem.

Comment: Also, do you really need to init() every time?

Comment: The init method has a return if its already done, and won't initialize every iteration. it is setup that way so that if it changes game states it will init the new game state.

Comment: Thanks a lot tilpner I found that instead of calculating the delta in the render method I should calculate it in the run method, enclosing the fps.tick() method also. Thank you for helping me with my problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
    // run() is being ran with a while(true) game loop
    public void run(Input input)
    {
         start = System.nanoTime();
         init();
         // Ran at 60 FPS
         if(fps.tick())
              render();
         // Ran as fast as possible
         update(input);
         end = System.nanoTime();

         // Time in ms
         delta =  (end-start)/1000000.0;
    }

    private void render()
    {       
         if(render.getGraphics() != null)
         {
             Graphics g = render.getBS().getDrawGraphics();
             g.drawImage(new BufferedImage(Reference.WIDTH*Reference.SCALE, Reference.HEIGHT*Reference.SCALE, 
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB), 0,0, AppGameContainer.canvas);
             activeState.render(render.getGraphics(), AppGameContainer.canvas);
             render.getGraphics().dispose();
             render.getBS().show();
         }
    }
```